# Create Json table in Json C#

Tags: c#, json

I am looking to create a json string in C# in the manner.
This is how it currently looks:

```json
[
   {
      "Vehiclename":"krieger",
      "Price":0,
      "Tank":120,
      "Trunk":100,
      "Speed":300,
      "Image":"krieger/krieger_selection.png",
      "Slide1":"krieger/krieger_side_new.png",
      "Slide2":"krieger/krieger_front_new.png",
      "Slide3":"krieger/krieger_back_new.png"
   }
]
```

How it should actually look:

```json
{
   "Vehiclename":"Krieger",
   "Price":"200000",
   "Tank":"100",
   "Trunk":"50",
   "Speed":"230",
   "Image":"krieger/krieger_selection.png",
   "Slide":[
      "krieger/krieger_side_new.png",
      "krieger/krieger_front_new.png",
      "krieger/krieger_back_new.png"
   ]
}
```

Here I create the json with the list I created before
And my 2nd code dadrunter the list is created and the items are entered into this list.
My C# Code:

```cs
var items = Database.Database.shopVehicleData.Where(x => x.ShopID == 1).Select(x => new
{
    Vehiclename = x.Vehiclename,
    Displayname = x.Displayname,
    Price = x.Price,
    Tank = x.Tank,
    Trunk = x.Trunk,
    Speed = x.Speed,
    Image = x.Image,
    Slide1 = x.Slide_1,
    Slide2 = x.Slide_2,
    Slide3 = x.Slide_3
});

// How i add this all
while (reader.Read())
{
    int ShopID = reader.GetInt32("ShopID");
    string Vehiclename = reader.GetString("Vehiclename");
    string Displayname = reader.GetString("Displayname");
    int Price = reader.GetInt32("Price");
    int Tank = reader.GetInt32("Tank");
    int Trunk = reader.GetInt32("Trunk");
    int Speed = reader.GetInt32("Speed");
    string Image = reader.GetString("Image");
    string Slide_1 = reader.GetString("Slide_1");
    string Slide_2 = reader.GetString("Slide_2");
    string Slide_3 = reader.GetString("Slide_3");

    shopVehicleData.Add(new ShopVehicleModel(ShopID, Vehiclename, Displayname, Price, Tank, Trunk, Speed, Image, Slide_1, Slide_2, Slide_3));
}
```

---

```
                            string Slide_2 = reader.GetString("Slide_2");
                            string Slide_3 = reader.GetString("Slide_3");

//OUTPUT
      "Slide1":"krieger/krieger_side_new.png",
      "Slide2":"krieger/krieger_front_new.png",
      "Slide3":"krieger/krieger_back_new.png"
```

What should actually look like this

```
      "Slide" : [
        "krieger/krieger_side_new.png", "krieger/krieger_front_new.png", "krieger/krieger_back_new.png"
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure exactly what the problem is. But using this class instead will make it the JSON format you want.

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string Vehiclename { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Tank { get; set; }
    public string Trunk { get; set; }
    public string Speed { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public List<string> Slide { get; set; }
}
```